# How do I enable HTTPS on a single-instance elastic beanstalk environment running express.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

I have a node.js server with express.js framework running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've got the server working fine on http, but I need to update it to https. It's worth noting that the environment is a single-instance environment.

I've been looking through documentation and guides for 4 hours now, and all I've managed to do break all access to my server. I've generated a certificate using Amazon Certificate Manager, and set up my load balancer to take HTTP requests from port 80 and send them to the server on port 80, and take HTTPS requests on port 443 and forward it to the server on port 443. The problem seems to be that the server doesn't listen on port 443. I've tried lots of stuff, including pretty much everything on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk documentation, but it just broke my server entirely. I'm getting pretty desperate, so any help would be appreciated. I'll be happy to answer questions if people need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the load balancer to listen at port 443 and forward the requests to the server on port 80. This is called "SSL Offloading".

Comment: The requestor said it was a "single instance" elastic beanstalk environment. They're likely referring to aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment/EnvironmentType == 'SingleInstance' which implies there is no load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to script the installation of the certificate on the instance itself.
I recommend you research LetsEncrypt as they provide SSL certificates for free and there is likely an automated process or express.js package you can install to get it working quickly.